# Android Q - Privacy change activity start through NFC

Tags: java, android, android-activity, background, android-10.0

https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/background-activity-starts

From this, it results that my payment app, which shows an Activity when a NFC transaction is performed, will not be able anymore to show anything to the user.

Has anyone have a clue what would be the new approach ?

Thanks!

I currently use the NFC service and it starts an Activity intent.

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(mApplicationContext, PaymentActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
mApplicationContext.startActivity(intent);
```

The Activity should be shown. It works now, but from Android Q, it won't

Comment: I am guessing that you do not control the NFC content and cannot adjust it to have some sort of NDEF record that could be handled by an activity's `<intent-filter>`. Presumably you will need to use a notification, perhaps one with a full-screen `Intent`.

Comment: it's really a poor user experience if i need to add a permanent notification on top... I understand Google wants to protect privacy, but here, this seems really messy...

Comment: It would not be permanent -- instead of launching the activity, you raise the notification. Whether you need a separate notification for this to be a foreground service is another matter, and one that would have been an issue since Android 8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the link, if you are having a HostApduService, then your app should work the same in Android Q.

If that is not your case, the simplest work around is to get "Draw over other apps" permissions. You can open activities if the app has been granted the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission by the user. I have tested this and working.

Technically, you are showing something on top of other apps without user's interaction, so this might be the right way to go.

Comment: My mistake, i missed the HostApduService exception. Thanks !